# Delete Divs before odd ID Div when double clicked

Tags: javascript, dom

A row of Divs have increasing ids. Double clicking a Div with an odd id deletes the Div before it. How do I delete The next Div before when I double click the odd Div again?

My current code cannot find the Ids of the divs before the even Div is deleted the first double click.

```
function doubleClick(e) {
if(e.target.id&1) {
    let squareBefore = document.getElementById(e.target.id-1);
    if(squareBefore === null) {
        alert("There is no Square before this one!");
    } else {
    squareBefore.remove();
}
```

}

Comment: id is a string....

Comment: What is the mark up. There probably is a better way without needing ids.